# Integrating the second derivative of numerical solution

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

```
pde1 = -y1''[x] - (2*y1'[x])/x + ((y1[x])^3 + y2[x])y1[x] == 0;
pde2 = y2''[x] + (2y2'[x])/x - (y1[x])^3 == 0;
sol = NDSolve[ {pde1, pde2, y1[1] == 0.001, y2[1] == -0.001,
  y1'[0.001] == 0.001, y2'[0.001] == 0.001}, {y1, y2}, {x,0.001, 20}]
```

I need to plot the values of `Integrate[y1''[x] x^2, {x, 0.001, 20}]`.

Answer (score 2):

Try `NIntegrate`

```
NIntegrate[y1''[x] x^2 /. sol[[1]], {x, 0.001, 20}]
(*-0.000826417*)
```

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate by parts twice and get an expression for the antiderivative:

```
parts[u_, v_, {x_, n_}] := 
 Sum[(-1)^m D[u, {x, m}] Nest[Integrate[#, x] &, v, m + 1], {m, 0, 
    n - 1}] + (-1)^n Integrate[
    D[u, {x, n}] Nest[Integrate[#, x] &, v, n], x];

parts[x^2, y1''[x], {x, 2}]
int1[x_] = % /. First[sol];
int1[20] - int1[0.001]
```

> ```
> (*
>   2 Integrate[y1[x], x] - 2 x y1[x] +  x^2 y1'[x]
>
>   -0.000826417
> *)
> ```

Plot:

```
Plot[int1[x], {x, 0.001, 20}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @BahiMido You're welcome. :)